# Why isn't my gaussian process regression failing?

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian-process

If I understand well, a homogeneous linear kernel imposes only one degre of freedom on the parametrized function.

I tried to make sklearn fail but it doesn't:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import DotProduct

kernel = DotProduct(sigma_0=0.0, sigma_0_bounds="fixed")
gpr = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel).fit(X=[[1], [2], [3]], y=[1, 2, 4])
print(gpr.predict([[3]]))
```

How can sklearn make inference (ie invert a singular matrix)?

Comment: in the docs for `GaussianProcessRegressor` there's the parameter `alpha` which adds `1e-10` by default to the diagonal of the kernel matrix to guarantee invertibility

Comment: @jld Oh thanks! I set sigma_0_bounds to be sure of the kernel but I didn't check the docs for GaussianProcessRegressor thoroughly

Comment: yeah, np! hope that helps